# Remove empty cells and their label cells from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a two-row table (label row and data row) that gets filled in with all relevant information about a running service, however, about half of the cells are empty at any given time depending on which test is run.

I'm looking for a jquery statement that will find all empty cells and hide them along with the label for that cell. I've searched quite a bit and found this code that is meant to hide the empty cells

```
$('table#yourTable tr').each(function(){
  if($(this).children('td:empty').length === $(this).children('td').length){
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

However, my "empty" cells are populated with "&nbsp" and not truly empty. Is there a way to hide a cell and its associated label cell?

Comment: You could either iterate through your td's and if &nbsp exists with nothing else, remove them, as currently the code you've found uses the `empty` psuedo-class which considers **any** text within an element to set it as non-empty.

More on the :empty psuedo-class here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: Example of how you may do this using jQuery here: https://jsfiddle.net/25gs6mcs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elems = $("tr").filter(function() {
    return this.querySelector("td").innerHTML === "&nbsp;"
  });
  elems.hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

following code will hide all of your not truly empty cell and it's label cell.

```
$(function () {
    var $label = $('tr:first');
    $('tr:last td').each(function (index, td) {
        var $td = $(td);
        if ($td.html() != '&nbsp;') return;

        $td.hide();
        $label.find('td:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
    });
});
```